# regexp in sublimetext2, multiple, changing variables

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I want to create from...

```
<description><b>this is test</b></description>
```

this...

```
<description><b>this is test</b></description>
<name>this is test</name>
```

in Sublime Text2. The number of words is variable, as well as the spaces (which may be inexisting).

I can setup a big number of variables, ex:

```
<description><b>(\w+)\s{0,3}(\w+)\s{0,3}(\w+)</b></description>
```

and replace by...

```
<description><b>$1 $2 $3</b></description>
<name><b>$1 $2 $3</name>
```

but if there is no space i get ...

```
<name><b>th i s</name>
```

Sorry but I am rookie on that... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<description><b>([^<]+)</b></description>
```

Should work. It says: after `<b>` match anything but a `<`. In other words: Anything until the next `</b>`.